# Find coordinates of intersection of two InfiniteLines

Tags: functions, vector, arguments

I have a couple of lines described by `InfiniteLine` and I need points where two different pairs of them intersect:

```
velAnormal[t_] = InfiniteLine[pointA, velocityAvector[pointA, t][[1]]]
velBnormal[t_] = InfiniteLine[pointB, Cross[velocityBvector[t]]]
velCnormal[t_] = InfiniteLine[pointC, velocityAvector[pointC, t][[1]]]
P1[t_] := RegionIntersection[velBnormal[t], velCnormal[t]]
P2[t_] := RegionIntersection[velBnormal[t], velAnormal[t]]
```

Both P1 and P2 give a `Point[x,y]` with coordinates, but only within certain operations: 
`@@`, `Delete[#,0] /@ P1[t]` or `Delete[0] /@ P1[t]` and maybe some other suggestions I found online all display error messages related to `RegionIntersection`, but attempting to use `P1[t]` or even `P1[0]` in a formula results a `Point[]` with the coordinates. How do I get coordinates and coordinates only?

Comment: Are you asking for `P1[0][[1]]`?

Comment: @Alan `P1[0][[1,1]]` for `x` and `P1[0][[1,2]]` for `y` worked, thanks. I'll mark this as an answer if you repost it.

Comment: The intersection of two `InfiniteLine[]` s is always a `Point[]`, so you need `First[]` if you want to extract the coordinates within `Point[]`.

Comment: @bqback it seems that you have already defined your lines in parametric form. It would be easy to obtain the intersection points by solving the system equation, wouldn`t it??

Answer (score 1):

The important point (pun intended) is that you can use `Part` to request the parts of any head.  In this case, the head is `Point`, which has one part, which is a point's coordinates in your case. (It can also be a list of coordinates.)  So you can extract the coordinates as `P1[0][[1]]`.  As J.M. notes, this is equivalent to `First@P1[0]`.  You indicate in your comment that you would like to assign these coordinates to variables `x` and `y`.  Since WL supports multiple assignment, you can do this as

```
{x,y}=First@P1[0]
```